# Enter date into HTML onload Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onload, getdate

I am trying to enter the current date when the page loads. I am able to store it to a variable, I am just having trouble entering that variable onto the page.

HTML:

```
<span id='test'>x</span>
```

Javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var month = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",    "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth();
  var currentMonth = month[mm];
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
  today = currentMonth + ' ' + dd + ', ' + yyyy;
  document.getElementById('test').innertext() = today;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8DeXF/1/)

Comment: `.innerText = "some text"` innerText, innerHTML are not functions, even if they were you do not assign values to the return of a function

Comment: I second what Patrick said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
document.getElementById('test').innertext() = today;
```

for this:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = today;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem at the following line of code because you treat the `innerText` property as if it was a `function` and you don't camel-case it (JavaScript is a case-sensitive language):

```
 document.getElementById('test').innertext() = today;
```

So change it to:

```
document.getElementById('test').innerText = today;
```

Here is the working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ynevet/cNCf4/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, it works

```
window.onload = function() {
      var month = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",    "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
      var today = new Date();
      var dd = today.getDate();
      var mm = today.getMonth();
      var currentMonth = month[mm];
      var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      today = currentMonth + ' ' + dd + ', ' + yyyy;
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = today;
    }
```